# YUI + Ajax get on Click event with FOR loop

Tags: ajax, yui, moodle, yui3

I'm trying to turn display Mysql queries results on a click event.
The results may be different, depending on the link that is clicked. So I've thought adding a FOR loop inside my **click** function. It seems I'm wrong with my code :

```
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.8.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
<script>
YUI().use("node", function (Y) { 
  for (var i=1; i<4; i++) { 
    Y.one("#link" + i).on('click', function ajaxFunction(i){

    var id = document.getElementById("link" + i).className;
    Y.io('query.php',
       {
  type: "GET",
  data: "id="+id,
  success: function (msg) {
        Y.one("#display_div" + i).setHTML(msg);
}
    });

        });
    };
});
</script>

<a href="#" id="link" class="(Test 1)"> Maths</a>
<div id="display_div1"></div>

<a href="#" id="link" class="FAQ"> Anglais</a>
<div id="display_div2"></div>
```

**This code is an translation in YUI3 of my working jQuery code :**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script languid="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
  for (var i=1; i<4; i++) { 
    $("#link" + i).click(makeDisplayCallback(i));
  }
});
function makeDisplayCallback(j) {
  return function() {
    ajaxFunction(j);
  };
}
function ajaxFunction(j){
var id = document.getElementById("link" + j).className;
$.ajax(
   {
  type: "GET",
  url: "query.php",
  data: "id="+id,
  success: function (msg) {
        $("#thema" + j).html(msg);
}
   });
};

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into a classical example of how references work in JavaScript. When the `success` callback is called, the value of `i` is always `2` because it already changed to the next iteration. What you need to do is wrap each callback in another function so each of them points to a different value of `i`.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
  Y.io(url, {
    on: {
      // on each iteration the success function is a different function
      success: (function (index) {
        return function (msg, result) {
          Y.one('#display_div' + index).setHTML(msg);
        };
      }(i)); // we pass it the current value of i
    }
  });
}
```